# ApplyThemeColorScheme for Word & Excel

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, vsto, powerpoint

I am developing VSTO for word, excel, powerpoint application. where I want to apply my custom color theme.
In PowerPoint application, I have done some R&D and finally, I got some help for PowerPoint VSTO.

Code: {To apply our custom color themes in current slide}
objSlide.ApplyThemeColorScheme(strThemeXmlFilePath);

But now a problem is that I want to implement same ColorScheme theme in Word & Excel both the application.

I have done enough R&D for that but I didn't get anything. 
Is there anyone who has an idea how to apply my custom color theme in word and excel application.

Comment: In Word, something like ActiveDocument.ApplyDocumentTheme("themefile_name") might do the job.  Cindy?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Maybe - not my area of expertise. It does work, but I can't get it to show when I query it using .ActiveTheme or .ActiveTheme.DisplayName. Note this is the entire theme. For just the colors, it looks like `ActiveDocument.Documenttheme.ThemeColorScheme.Load *filename*` works.